# Empty string comparison is failing

Tags: c#, string

Currently writing a simple reservation. Right now I have a multidimensional string array that holds the passengers name and I am trying to iterate through that array and see whether there are any open seats so I know whether or not to add them to a waiting list.

```
        // Check how many seats are taken
        for (int i = 0; i <= nameArray.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= nameArray.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
            {
                if (nameArray[i, j] == "")
                {
                    seatsFilled--;
                }
                else
                {
                    seatsFilled++;
                }
            }
        }
```

For some reason when I debug, I notice that this line

```
if (nameArray[i, j] == "")
```

Doesn't do anything at all and gets skipped over despite there being no names in the array. I cannot for the life of me figure out why. Any suggestions?

Comment: "" is a valid string - a Empty one. "" is not the same as "null" Even if there is no human readable name in there, it could still be a empty string.

Comment: *"Doesn't do anything at all"* - Sure it does.  It compares that array element with an empty string.  If that array element is *anything other than* an empty string, this comparison results in `false`.  When you debug, what *specifically* does the array contain?  What are you expecting it to contain?  Why?

Comment: When you're debugging your code you can easily see the value of `nameArray[i, j]` in the current context in debugger's Watch, so it's really easy to check why the condition is not true. Where's the problem?

Comment: Try using `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(nameArray[i, j]))` instead.

Answer (score 1):

One of the reason i can see is the comparison may have the whitespace. Try this

```
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nameArray[i, j]))
```

Comment: " " would not equal "". But yes, the basic problem is indeed Empty Strings are not no strings.

Comment: In this user case should be `string.IsNullOrEmpty`, I agree usually `IsNullOrWhitespace` is more useful, but it's not the same.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

First I would create some interfaces and models that would define the structure of the seat. Make sure to account for seat restrictions.

```
    public interface ISeat
    {
        int RowNumber { get; }
        string SeatLetter { get; }
        PassangerModel Passenger { get; }
    }
```

We want to allow some of the seats to be restricted based on passenger age and height. Hard coding that into each seat is nasty so instead I created a SeatRestriction class that has a predicate in it. This predicate will take the passenger model in and return a result. So for example you could create a SeatRestriction that checked a passengers height or age to make sure they can open emergency doors.

```
    public class SeatRestriction
    {
        public Predicate<PassangerModel> Restriction { get; private set; }

        public SeatRestriction(Predicate<PassangerModel> restriction)
        {
            Restriction = restriction;
        }
    }
```

The passenger model can actually be much more verbose than this. I'm assuming here no dietary needs. Maybe this is a reservation system for Spirit Airlines.

```
    public class PassangerModel
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }

        public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }

        public string CreditCardName { get; set; }
        public string CreditCardNumber { get; set; }
        public string CreditCardExpiration { get; set; }
        public string CreditCardSecurityPin { get; set; }
    }
```

Next We come to our seat class. This class allows us to see if a passenger is assigned to the seat. Take note that it also asserts prior to adding the passenger to the seat if the passenger meets the restrictions, if any.

```
    public interface IRestrictedSeat
    {
        List<SeatRestriction> Restrictions { get; }

        bool AssertQualifiedPassenger(PassangerModel passenger);
    }

    public class Seat : ISeat, IRestrictedSeat
    {
        public bool IsSeatReserved { get { return Passenger != null; } }

        public int RowNumber { get; private set; }

        public string SeatLetter { get; private set; }

        public PassangerModel Passenger { get; private set; }

        public List<SeatRestriction> Restrictions { get; private set; }

        public Seat(int rowNumber, string seatLetter)
        {
            Restrictions = new List<SeatRestriction>();
            RowNumber = rowNumber;
            SeatLetter = seatLetter;
        }

        public bool TryAddPassenger(PassangerModel passanger)
        {
            if (AssertQualifiedPassenger(passanger))
            {
                Passenger = passenger;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public bool AssertQualifiedPassenger(PassangerModel passenger)
        {
            foreach(SeatRestriction restriction in Restrictions)
            {
                if (!restriction.Restriction(passenger))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Finally we get to the row. Our row knows how manys seats it has and what its number is. You should be able to add seats to it and then call `GetAvailableSeats` to get the seats that are left in this row.

```
    public class SeatRow
    {
        public int TotalSeats { get; private set; }
        public int RowNumber { get; private set; }

        public List<Seat> Seats { get; private set; }

        public SeatRow(int seatsInRow, int rowNumber)
        {
            TotalSeats = seatsInRow;
            RowNumber = rowNumber;
        }

        public bool TryAddSeatToRow(Seat seat)
        {
            if(Seats.Count <= TotalSeats && seat.RowNumber == RowNumber)
            {
                Seats.Add(seat);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<Seat> GetAvailableSeats()
        {
            return Seats.Where(seat => seat.IsSeatReserved == false);
        }

    }
```

The long and short of this answer is there's a million ways to solve CIS problems and to not rely on stack overflow while you're in school/learning. Good luck and welcome to the club :-)

Answer (score 0):

`if (nameArray[i, j] == "")`

> Doesn't do anything at all and gets skipped over despite there being **no names in the array.**

That line is inside a loop that iterates through the items in the array. If the array is empty then this will never get executed.